# Serge Lang: Linear Algebra, Sylvester’s Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

On page 139 of the second edition of Lang’s *Linear Algebra*, I’m not quite sure how to do the second part of this exercise related to Sylvester’s Theorem:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $<,>$ be a scalar product on $V$. Show that V admits a direct sum decomposition $V=V^+ \oplus V^- \oplus V_0$ ... Show that the dimensions of the spaces $V^+, V^-$ are the same in all such decompositions.

$V^+$ is the set of all vectors such that if they’re nonzero then they have strictly positive norm. $V^-$ is the same except with strictly negative norm. $V_0$ is the set of all vectors such that $<v,w>=0$ for all $w\in V$.

I’m not sure at all how to do this. I did the first part of the problem and I wanted to use one of its consequences: $\mathrm{dim}V = \mathrm{dim}V^+ + \mathrm{dim}V^- + \mathrm{dim}V_0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, $V^+$ is _not_ the set of all positive vectors. Namely, if you add a vector from $V_0$ to a vector from $V^+$, it remains positive. Here is a way to prove the claim: There is a symmetric linear map $G : V\to V$ such that $<x,y> = \langle Gx,y\rangle$ for all $x,y\in V$. Here, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product w.r.t. some fixed basis. Now, choose $V^+$ as the span of all eigenvectors of $G$ corresponding to positive eigenvalues, $V^-$ as the span of all eigenvectors of $G$ corresponding to negative eigenvalues, and $V_0 = \ker G$.

Comment: I essentially read $V^+$ straight from the text so I’m not quite sure what you’re saying in the beginning.

Comment: You can be sure. I even prove it.

Comment: The usual statement is that there's an orthonormal basis consisting of positive vectors, negative vectors, and null vectors.

Comment: I don’t understand how that is different from what I put though.

Comment: Null vectors are vectors of length $0$, i.e., satisfying $\langle v,v\rangle = 0$. I also stipulated that these basis vectors are going to give rise to orthogonal subspaces.